# Why are there multiple prefixes for the same root word?

Tags: prefixes

The root word I'm thinking of is comfort; two types of prefixes are applied to it, in the words *discomfort* and *uncomfortable*. Why is this?

Comment: Lots of roots have different prefixes--are you specifically asking about the use of. Both un and dis?

Comment: I'm asking why one would apply two different prefixes (that mean the same/similar things) to one word.

Comment: "Similar" - so not the same meaning, so different prefixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the context you want to use the root word, you will have to use a different prefix to explain what you mean.

Here the definitions of both words:

> **dis·com·fort**  *(ds-kmfrt)* noun
>
> 1. Mental or bodily distress.
> 2. Something that disturbs one's comfort; an annoyance.
>
> **un·com·fort·a·ble**  *(n-kmfr-t-bl, -kmft-)* adj.
>
> 1. Ill at ease; uneasy.
> 2. Causing anxiety; disquieting.

Even though both words use same root word and have a very similar meaning they are not synonyms, thus you would use each in a different context.

**discomfort in a sentence:**

> *Applying hot packs or hot moist towels may help relieve **discomfort**.*

**uncomfortable in a sentence:**

> *Most patients consider the test to be only slightly **uncomfortable**.*

Comment: Nor do they belong to the same word class.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of similar prefixes (and suffixes, and roots).  Some of the redundancy is because it comes from different languages. (For example, what is the difference between *sept-* and *hept-*? *Sept-* is from Latin, and *hept-* is from Greek.)

On the other hand, sometimes the same spelling means different things because it comes from both languages. (For instance, *acr-* in Greek means 'high' like in *acrobat*, whereas in Latin it means 'sharp' or 'bitter' like in *acrimony*.)

There are also some subtle differences in the meaning of the words in the original language. (For instance *ab-* and *de-* are both Latin, meaning 'away'. However, *ab-* was used as an ablative noun and *de-* was a preposition.  You couldn't use them the same way, even if they had a lot in common.)